# Getting data to line up C++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble getting data to line up. I want it to appear like

```
ISRAEL WILKINS          938-701-1455
BRUCE PERRY             540-916-2956
VALENTIN RIVERS         726-204-2377
```

but it's coming out as

```
NGUYEN KAYLA                  484-322-1527
PERKINS THEODORE                  723-668-3397
PERRY BRUCE                  540-916-2956
RIVERS VALENTIN                  726-204-2377
```

my code is this

```
 cout  << left << R.lastname << " " << R.firstname  <<right << setw(30)  << R.phonenumber <<endl;
```

What am I doing wrong that is not making the phone numbers aligned?

Comment: All the number fields are right aligned 30 chars so 30 chars from the last character in the name, you need to make the names print out in a fixed length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setw() to set the minimum number of characters you want to be written and left to output the data to the left. Like this:

```
cout << setw(8) << left << myvec[i][0];
```

This should fill the empty space with spaces but if not, then you can do:

```
cout << setw(8) << left << setfill(' ') << myvec[i][0];
```

You will need to #include  for this.
try it , wish that will help you